# Convert cv::Mat to std::vector without copying

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, alignment, mat

I've this function:

```
void foo(cv::Mat &mat){
  float *p = mat.ptr<float>(0);
  //modify mat values through p
}
```

And I have this code that calls the function:

```
void bar(std::vector<unsigned char> &vec){
  //...
  cv::Mat res(m, n, CV_32FC1, (void *)&workspace.front());
}
```

However, the code above has a performance problem: `vec` isn't probably aligned. In fact, the Intel compiler says that `reference *out has unaligned access`. I hope that this is the reason.

Btw, as I found out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724903/is-this-code-correct-to-allocate-two-aligned-cvmat) question, `cv::Mat` is going to be aligned. So a simple workaround would be to:

1. Create `cv::Mat res(m,n)`
2. Call `foo(m);`
3. Assign the `vec` pointer to `m.ptr<float>(0)`

As you can imagine, performance here are crucial, so deep-copies are out of questions.

I tried the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681713/convert-mat-to-array-vector-in-opencv) question:

```
vec = res.data;
```

But I get a compiler error. Besides, I don't know if this code above is going to do an (inefficient) copy, or just change the pointed data by `vec`.

How can I do this smoothly? Otherwise, another workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681713/convert-mat-to-array-vector-in-opencv)

```
std::vector<uchar> array;
if (mat.isContinuous()) {
  array.assign(mat.datastart, mat.dataend);
} else {
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
    array.insert(array.end(), mat.ptr<uchar>(i), mat.ptr<uchar>(i)+mat.cols);
  }
}

//p.s.: For cv::Mats of other types, like CV_32F, you should do like this:

std::vector<float> array;
if (mat.isContinuous()) {
  array.assign((float*)mat.datastart, (float*)mat.dataend);
} else {
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
    array.insert(array.end(), (float*)mat.ptr<uchar>(i), (float*)mat.ptr<uchar>(i)+mat.cols);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid that this is going to do a deep copy of the elements, not of the references (and so it would be inefficient), right? In other words, this is going to be linear.

Comment: sorry i did not pay attention. maybe a plain pointer array, i also asked a friend who also works with open CV and he pointed to the same direction.